# Xamarin - avoi back button title on await Navigation.PushAsync

Tags: xamarin, navigation

How can avoid the back button title that appear when await Navigation.PushAsync is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Back Button Title to null in your root page. Like this:

> NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, ""); //put this in your page's constructor